# accessing bit fields in structure

Tags: c

I am new to the bit fields concept. I am trying to access the elements in the structure, but it is showing the error at `aa=v` like this.

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘cc’ from type ‘long unsigned int ’
```

And it is showing error if I typecasted at `aa= (cc)v;`

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

I tried accessing the elements by declaring a pointer to a structure. I did well in this case, but in this case I do not declare a pointer to a structure and I have to access the elements. How can I overcome this error.

Thanks for any help in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct 
{
        unsigned long a:8;
    unsigned long b:8;
    unsigned long c:8;
    unsigned long d:8;
}cc;


int main()
{ 
        cc aa ;
    unsigned long v = 1458;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(aa));
    aa=v;    // aa= (cc)v;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", aa.a,aa.b,aa.c,aa.d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use `uint8_t`s from `inttypes.h` if you need 8 bit sized bitfields (sorry if this is obvious).

Answer (score 7):

If you intend to access the same data as multiple data-types, then you need to use an [**`union` in C**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B). Take a look at the following snippet that will

1. Write to a union treating it as a 32bit integer
   *(and then)*
2. Access the data back as 4 individual 8bit bit-fields
   *(and also for good measure)*
3. Access the same data back again as a 32bit integer

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned long a:8;
    unsigned long b:8;
    unsigned long c:8;
    unsigned long d:8;
}bitfields;

union data{
    unsigned long i;
    bitfields bf;
};

int main()
{ 
    union data x;
    unsigned long v = 0xaabbccdd;
    printf("sizeof x is %dbytes\n",sizeof(x));

    /* write to the union treating it as a single integer */
    x.i = v;

    /* read from the union treating it as a bitfields structure */
    printf("%x %x %x %x\n", x.bf.a, x.bf.b, x.bf.c, x.bf.d);

    /* read from the union treating it as an integer */
    printf("0x%x\n", x.i);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that when union is accessed as an integer, the endian-ness of the system determines the order of the individual bit-fields. Hence the above program on a 32bit x86 PC (little-endian) will output :

```
sizeof x is 4bytes
dd cc bb aa
0xaabbccdd
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `aa` is a structure and `v` is not, the types are *incompatible* just like the error message says. Even if `cc` is a structure of bitfields, it still can only be used as a structure, with separate members, and not like an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you wanted to assign a 4 byte sized long to your 4 byte sized struct. If yes, this might be for you:

```
 aa = *(cc*)&v;
```

However you should be aware about endianness in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
aa.a = v;
```

Instead of

```
aa = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign a `long` to a `struct` which are incompatible.

you can assign inner value of cc to v:

```
cc c;
unsigned long v = 1458;
c.b = v;
```

if you want the first 8 bits to be in `a` for example you can do

```
cc c;
unsigned long v = 1458;
c.a = v % 255;
c.b = v / 255 % 65280;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to overflow? Isn't 255 the maximum integer value a field of eight bits can hold?

Comment: 1458 binary value is : 10110110010; my aim is to get first 8 bits into structure element a, i.e,10110010 = 178; and next 8 bits to element b:101=5....If I am doing as u said the first element is taking first 8 bits and remaining elements it is showing 0.....

Comment: then you can use module for that @user2641184