# How do I cast the struct to a char pointer?

Tags: struct, bit-manipulation, spi

Effectively I want to make an spi interface where I'll be able to change bits 18-22 and bits 1-16 separately (I want a one hot address on bits 1-16 and a binary coded decimal on bits 18-22) here's how I intend on implementing the struct

```cpp
struct spi_out
{
unsigned int BCDADDR : 4
unsigned int OHADDR  : 16
/// Some other spi bit addresses making up the rest of the 3 bytes
```

So here's my problem

I want to be able to access BCD address and encode it directly eg: `spi_out.bcd = 5// in order to access the 6th cell`but I also want to use the operator function to format the bits the way I need them since I need the variables in the order I put them in and I can't figure out a simple way of doing this since I wouldn't want to have to put an LUT inside an operator function but I need to be able to cast the string of bits to a char pointer so the 3 bytes of information from the function can be fed to a hardware abstraction function`HAL_SPI_Transmit()` , like I know the data is kept as 3 bytes so I don't see why I can't access them as such>:/

Comment: 4-bit BCD is indistinguishable from a plain integer.  You do not need to do any kind of conversion, you can simply assign the values from 0 to 9 and the result will be correct as BCD.

Comment: When you say "operator function" do you mean a C++ overloaded operator?

Comment: Your question is very unclear about what you want to convert to a pointer.  `HAL_SPI_Transmit` requires a pointer to the data to send.  In this case you must not convert the struct to a pointer, you must create a pointer to the struct in memory.  This is just the normal & operator.   Please edit the question to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i have come to appreciate that my question was worded in such an annoying confusing way but i have actually found an answer to my own question, that is to user the Union keyword, this means i can define a union that means i can create a type that can be treated as a struct to access the individual bits or an array of 4 chars. I did not realize this existed but here is a link to the stack overflow question where i found my answer
[accessing bit fields in structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989483/accessing-bit-fields-in-structure)
sorry guys

Comment: _Union aliasing_ is not always a good idea.

Comment: Why not? What is the problem?

Comment: As usual: 1) BE architectures, 2) padding in the structures. And bit fields themselves are beasts in the C programming language. To have a good code one should avoid bit fields as much as possible. They are harmful.